# Auto-Override files with a git pull?

Tags: git

I run this command:

```
git pull https://bitbucket.org/NAME
```

Then it pops up an error:

```
From https://bitbucket.org/NAME/project-tool
 * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
Auto-merging includes/top.php
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in includes/top.php
```

then it has:

```
(Branch|MERGING)
```

Which I can override with this, but I just want to pull this repository and don't care if it overrides every file (which I have backed up).

```
git reset --merge
```

How do you use git to pull in files and auto merge and override your current files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this gets the file from the remote and stores it on the local repository

```
git fetch https://bitbucket.org/NAME
```

use the following command if you want to set your local branch to match the remote thus removing local branch changes. Make sure local files are backed up.

```
git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD
```